# django urls regular expressions

Tags: django

So i have a main urls.py that looks like this:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^users/(?P<username>.*)/', include('app.urls')), 
url(r'^users/(?P<username>.*)$',direct_to_template,{'template':'accounts/profile.html'}, name='profile'),)
```

and a app.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^app/create/$', create_city ,name='create_city'),)
```

my problem is, when i localhost:8000/users/michael/app/create/ it doesn't call my view. I have tried changing the order of the urls with no luck so i believe my problem is with the regular expressions but with no idea on what to change, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The named group `(?P<username>.*)` will match any characters, zero or more times. in your username, including forward slashes.

In url patterns, it would be more common to use `(?P<username>[-\w]+)`. This would match at least one character from the set of lowercase a-z, uppercase A-Z, digits 0-9 hyphens and underscores.

I also recommend that you add a trailing slash to your pattern for your `profile` view.

Putting it all together, I suggest you use the following as a starting point for your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^users/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$',direct_to_template, {'template':'accounts/profile.html'}, name='profile'), 
   (r'^users/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/', include('app.urls')), 
)
```

Comment: i there, i tried your aproach and it didnt work. i get a 404 when i put http://localhost:8000/users/brian/  
i changed it to (r'^users/(\w+)/', include('app.urls')), and it now works. Do you know why?

Comment: There was a typo in my profile url pattern. The plus sign belongs outside the square brackets. It should work now.

Comment: how it works, thanks dude. By the way can you explain the difference with the solution that i posted earlier? thanks

Comment: `[-\w]+` matches everything that `\w+` matches, but it matches hyphens as well. The other difference is that my pattern uses [named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups), and yours does not.

Comment: oops i think i doesn't work after all (was running the wrong code). i get a TypeError at /users/admin/app/create:  create_city() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username' .
tried switching your order around but still no luck. 
by the way, i have a "return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/%s/' % request.user.username)" on my create_city()

Comment: i got it working by (r'^users/([-\w]+)/',include('smarturbia.urls')),
is this ok?

Comment: Using named groups can be useful, but if your urls are working as you want then you don't need to change. If you use named groups, then the names need to match the arguments of your view, i.e. the `create_city` function should be defined as `def create_city(request, username)`.

Comment: oh,i think i get it now. I did what you said and it works. this way i can use the username in the create_city argument to ensure that the username is valid also right?

Comment: Yes, you can check the username in the `create_city` view.